# Mobile Automation using HP UFT

Tags: testing, mobile, automated-tests, hp-uft, seetest

Is it possible to run Automation tests on mobile using HP UFT / QTP ? I have heard about paid add-in's like perfecto and seetest. But I wish to test on my local machine using real device or emulator.

Answer (score 1):

There is support for testing mobile applications built in to UFT when working with [HP Mobile Center](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/software-solutions/mobile-testing/) (since version UFT 12.02).

This solution allows testing on real devices but you'll have to install a Red Hat machine as the server (this can be a VM).

Comment: I believe mobile center is commercial tool. Is there any free add in ?

Answer (score 1):

Using seetest addin you can use your local machine, real device or emulator to test. You can have a 15 days free trial for it in case you want to try it out. M-eux from Jamo Solutions also provides addin for HP UFT and works with real devices and emulators.

Comment: Thank you. But I require free add in's ( Sorry that I did not mention it in my question). 15 days not enough.

Comment: Free add-ins for HP UFT for mobile automation are not available yet. All are paid tools. I would suggest go for appium if you want free tool. it won't work with uft.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with Perfecto Plugin with UFT. Works well. You can work on emulator or real device.